# How to set a custom free shipping amount for each quote?

Tags: magento-1, shipping, shipping-methods, quote, free-shipping

I need to set a custom free-shipping threshold (in config this is `carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal` and can be set in the back-end) for each quote subtotal. So quotes above this subtotal amount will have free shipping applied. The subtotal-amount will change dynamically (by user) and should revert to default value set in back end when user is logged off.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: can not understand by `free-shipping subtotal threshold for each quote(cart`.plz explain

Comment: Hi Amit. I've made an edit.

Comment: what mean by `The subtotal-amount will change dynamically(by user) and should revert to default value set in back end when user is logged off` .please  explain brefly

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish a free shipping/per customer/per minimum subtotal by :

1. Adding a new customer entity attribute, which will be the place to edit the minimum per order for each customer.
   [Adding custom attribute to Customer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/14163/adding-custom-attribute-to-customer)
2. After this you will need to rewrite the class `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping` in `app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php` , specifically in the `collectRates()` method. instead of checking for `$this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal')` we will check the customer subtotal from the attribute we created in point one.

```php
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    $minimumOrderAmount = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()->getNewAttrubuteYouCreated();
} else {
    $minimumOrderAmount = $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal');
}

if (($request->getFreeShipping())
    || ($request->getBaseSubtotalInclTax() >= $minimumOrderAmount)
) {
    $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

    $method->setCarrier('freeshipping');
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod('freeshipping');
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    $method->setPrice('0.00');
    $method->setCost('0.00');

    $result->append($method);
}
```

Some links to help:
http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Comment: Thanks Rabee. Although it didn't work for some reason(despite the condition was met the shipping rate wasn't free) it pointed me in the right direction. I've overwritten Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Freeshipping as advised here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3670/programmatically-set-free-shipping-from-an-observer.

Comment: @Alan glad you found the answer, you didnt need to add a customer attribute at the end ? how did you make it customer specific ? I am going to double check my answer also.