# Magento 2 Exclude Free shipping method for specific products

Tags: magento2.3, shipping, shipping-methods, free-shipping

I have created one attribute for products, if that attribute value is yes than only it will be eligible for free shipping and other products will be excluded from free shipping. so when i add that product in the cart it wont count in free shipping.

Comment: use addto cart event and in that event you get current items quote data check your specific product attribute value and then apply this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/250486/82670

Comment: i think it can be possible with freeshipping model itself. so we do not need to check separately for cart and order level.

Answer (score 2):

> Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Magento_Shipping_Model_Shipping" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Plugin/Magento/Shipping/Model/Shipping.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Shipping\Model;
 
class Shipping
{
    protected $product;
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->product = $product; 
    }
 
    public function aroundCollectCarrierRates(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $carrierCode,
        $request
    ) {
        $noFreeShipping = false;
        $allItems = $request->getAllItems();
         
        foreach ($allItems as $item) {    
            $_product = $this->product->create()->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
        
            if (condition) { //here you can check your attribute value
                $noFreeShipping = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($noFreeShipping && $carrierCode == 'freeshipping') {
            return false;
        }
        $result = $proceed($carrierCode, $request);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you !! This will work but if i add two products in the cart in which one product has attribute value 0 and other has attribute value 1 than this will not work.

Comment: If you go with an approach like this, i would suggest you add an extension attribute on the quote item instead of loading the products one by one to validate the condition (performance wise this might get costly otherwise).

Comment: you can check in forecah loop

Comment: @DianaBotean yes good idea, i will try that. Thank you :) keep helping.

Comment: @RkRathod still not working.

Comment: Please attach your code...

Comment: @RkRathod i have used the same which you have posted. the difference is i just completed the loop at the last.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way to achieve this is to create a new shipping method that could extend the OOTB Magento freeshipping carrier `vendor/magento/module-offline-shipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php` (or it could be a completely new carrier with no dependencies to Magento default) and performs the logic by validating the items in the `collectRates()` method.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank You! Totally agree with you! but i have to customize the default shipping method as per requirement.

Comment: Mam, can you please help me in this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/329164/magento-2-how-can-i-check-if-field-has-data-while-viewing-the-formui-component

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I Override the offlineshipping model file and deduct the price of the product which i wanted to exclude from the free shipping and set the new Package Value.

Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping" />
</config>
```

Vendor/Magento/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Magento\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;

/**
 * Free shipping model
 *
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Freeshipping extends \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'freeshipping';

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isFixed = true;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $rateResultFactory, $rateMethodFactory, $data);
    }

    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        $this->_updateFreeMethodQuote($request);

        /* check your condition here start */
        foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
            if(condition){
               $request->setPackageValueWithDiscount($request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() - $item->getRowTotal());
                continue;
            }
        }
        /* check your condition here end*/

        if ($request->getFreeShipping() || $request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() >= $this->getConfigData(
            'free_shipping_subtotal'
        )
        ) {

            /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

            $method->setCarrier('freeshipping');
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod('freeshipping');
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            $method->setPrice('0.00');
            $method->setCost('0.00');

            $result->append($method);
        } elseif ($this->getConfigData('showmethod')) {
            $error = $this->_rateErrorFactory->create();
            $error->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $error->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
            $errorMsg = $this->getConfigData('specificerrmsg');
            $error->setErrorMessage(
                $errorMsg ? $errorMsg : __(
                    'Sorry, but we can\'t deliver to the destination country with this shipping module.'
                )
            );
            return $error;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use your function for the same functionality. I need to add "Freeshipping" only, if ALL products meet a specific product attribute. Plugin seems working, but how can I do this?  
What code do I need between this lines?   
/* check your condition here start */

Comment: @Marcel in condition you just need to check the product attribute value.